# Placeholders for a text in a pdf Java-PDFBox?

Tags: java, pdfbox

Can we make placeholders for a text in a pdf and mark them with an id (similar to html tags) and just fill that placeholder with our text, of whichever length in Java, using PdfBox?

Answer (score 1):

> Can we make placeholders for a text in a pdf and mark them with an id (similar to html tags) and just fill that placeholder with our text, of whichever length

No, at least not without a great deal of coding around it.

The reason is that PDF is a format for documents with a finished layout.

If you *fill that placeholder with your text, of whichever length*, in particular in case of filling with a long text, the contents of the document would have to be re-flowed, text following the placeholder would have to be moved down, text already at the bottom of the page body would have to be moved to the next page, etc.

As PDF documents in general don't contain information on stuff like margins, text alignments, etc., that task is severely non-trivial.

(There also are other issues, e.g. embedded font subsets without the glyphs of your replacement text or backgrounds or borders without linkage to the "backgrounded" or "bordered" text.)

I'm not aware of an automatized general purpose implementation of that task, in particular not in free PDF libraries.

Comment: as we now, we can put tags on different sections in pdf document. The thing I'm interested is if we can for example say: put this text below some section programatically- in java using pdfbox, or in any other language?

Comment: What you can easily do is stamp text onto an existing pdf. *"below some section"* is unclear, how do you want to recognise that end? The pdf format does not require tagging to indicate where a "section" starts or ends. Thus you need something to recognise the end.

Comment: Bellow section means like::: below paragraph1, below header... things like that :) and I don't know how to mark that, nor how to access to that 'tags'..

Comment: pdfs usually don't know paragraphs or headers. At most you can expect a concept of text lines.