# PDFBox: Replace text placeholder with a signature form field

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

First let me say that I am a newcomer to PDFBox and the underlying PDF format.

I have an incoming PDF *(converted from HTML)* that contains a **placeholder** for a signature field. I am able to create the `PDAcroForm` and signature `PDSignatureField`. Also, I can absolutely position the form on the page. What I struggle to figure out is how to find the text placeholder and anchor the form at that location...

Here is my abbreviated code:

```
try (
        final PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(context.getInboundPDF());
        final ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
) {

    final PDPage page = document.getPage(0);

    final PDAcroForm acroForm = new PDAcroForm(document);
    document.getDocumentCatalog().setAcroForm(acroForm);

    final PDSignatureField signatureField = new PDSignatureField(acroForm);
    acroForm.getFields().add(signatureField);           

    final PDAnnotationWidget widget = signatureField.getWidgets().get(0);
    final PDRectangle rectangle = new PDRectangle(50, 650, 200, 50);
    widget.setRectangle(rectangle);
    widget.setPage(page);
    page.getAnnotations().add(widget);          

    document.save(outputStream);

    context.setOutboundPDF(outputStream.toByteArray());

} catch(final Exception e) {
    LOG.error(e.getMessage(), e);
}
```

I understand that the absolute positioning results from the dimensional data on the `PDRectangle` object. Do form elements have to always be positioned absolutely? Can one find the a paragraph placeholder and replace it with the signature field widget? Can I push the subsequent content down the page to accommodate the height difference between the signature field and it placeholder? If so, how would one deal with page overflow?

Thanks so much.

Comment: I notice from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49729775/placeholders-for-a-text-in-a-pdf-java-pdfbox that filling in a placeholder will involve considerable code around reflowing the document. Has anyone done this? Is it feasible, or do I need to be satisfied with appending the form to the end of the content on the given page? Assuming I go the appending route, how do I actually find the end of content position and append the signature field?

Comment: The signature examples in the source code download support using a placeholder when the name is known.

Comment: @Tilman are you sure you have the same connotation as the OP in respect to placeholder? I think he means some regular page content text like `[signature]`, and I assume you mean an empty, unsigned signature field. Brulejr, can you clarify?

Comment: @mki Your interpretation is correct. Sorry for my lack of clarity.

Comment: @mki @Tilman I have been experimenting with extracting the text using `PDFTextStripper`, separating it into lines, and reflowing it. This would give me the opportunity to easily recognize and replace a `[signature]` placeholder. I theorize that I should even be able to handle both the difference in height and page overflow easily. My current stumbling block is finding all the font, font size, and page dimensional information...

Comment: In general the difficult part may be removing the textual placeholder. The information you are looking for, on the other hand is easy to get.  That being said, does the placeholder need to be removed at all? If it already is e.g. drawn white on white, not removing it would probably be ok...

Comment: We are doing something similar: Locating a white textual placeholder and afterwards add an empty signature field (with some offset etc.) to it...

Comment: See the `PrintTextLocations.java` and `DrawPrintTextLocations.java` examples on how to get sizes and positions.